# Unable to find custom Blender operator in F3 operator search (Blender 2.9)

Tags: python, blender

I am working through this tutorial:
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/scripting/addon_tutorial.html

I have copied the script below from the tutorial and it compiles without any errors when I run the script. I should be able to search "Move X by One" in the operator search menu (`F3`) to execute the operator, but it does not show up in the operator search menu. How can I get the operator to show up in the search menu? Has something changed in blender 2.9?

```py
bl_info = {
    "name": "Move X Axis",
    "category": "Object"
}

import bpy

class ObjectMoveX(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.move_x"
    bl_label = "Move X by One"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):
        scene = context.scene
        for obj in scene.objects:
            obj.location.x += 1.0

        return {'FINISHED'}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ObjectMoveX)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ObjectMoveX)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: When I run it in blender 2.82 it works fine

Comment: I met the same issue, I tested against 2.90 and 2.91, not shown

Comment: tried 2.83.6 lts , works

Answer (score 14):

You must enable the checkbox `Developer Extras` under `Preferences -> Interface`, and then maybe reload the addon. You probably had this figured out in the past, but lost the setting when upgrading.

Comment: Another way this can happen is if Blender crashed over the course of the session in which you first enabled `Developer Extras`. Any preferences set in a session that ends up crashing will be reset.

Answer (score 12):

#### Blender 2.90.1

As pointed out by other users, the API has been updated. You can see the release notes here:
[Blender 2.90: Python API](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.90/Python_API#Compatibility) where it says:

> ...add-ons that expose operators only through search need to be updated.

This is due to the new addition of the operator search that only searches through menus (accessed by `F3`). Because of this, you need to add the operator to a menu.

Add the `menu_func` function:

```
def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(ObjectMoveX.bl_idname)
```

And update the `register` function:

```
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ObjectMoveX)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.append(menu_func)
```

You can now either access your operator via the operator search (`F3`) or through the menus, i.e. `Object>YourOperatorName`

If you do not want these to be accessible via these menus, the release notes also mention:

> For more obscure operators that are for example intended mainly for developers, we recommend adding them in the TOPBAR_MT_app_system menu. This is accessible through the System menu under the Blender icon in the top bar.

Comment: Thanks, I have spend a lot of time trying to figure it out why It wasn't working. They should update their documentation....

Comment: @ElLocoCocoLoco you're right. If something like this is announced in the release logs, it would definitely make sense for them to update their tutorials.

Comment: Just **enable Developer Extras** *(User Preferences > Interface)*. There is no need to add operators to menus.

Answer (score 3):

Sybren aknowledged this in [this post](https://developer.blender.org/T74157#1024859).
The solution in my case was to copy [this example](https://developer.blender.org/T74157#1024859). Here how it works:

1. Add this after your call to *register_class()*: `bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_app_system.append(menu_func)`
2. Add the `menu_func(self, context)` with:
   `self.layout.operator(` *your argument to register_class* `.bl_idname)`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with 2.90.0, but when I upgraded to 2.90.1 it works perfectly.
Just tested this with the code from your question. So I recommend you to try 2.90.1.
For me it was updated silently with my system updates. If you want to do it manually, you can download it here:
https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.90/

(I cannot write a comment since I don't have enough stack overflow points)